created a templete folder that includes a nav bar.html but it is not showing up on the browser. i keep getting templete does not exist
enter image description herenav bar is not showing and giving this error
TemplateDoesNotExist at /navbar/ in the browser. i have created a folder and put in the nav bar as shown in the screenshot provided. if anyone can tell me the error. Is it because of the layout of my folders?
wanted the nav bar to show up enter image description here

the screenshot is not visible. What are your python files that you are referencing the template in?

hello. it is in vs code. i have also attached the photo

instead of 'navbar/navbar.html' you should do 'templete/navbar.html' as the navbar.html is in the templete folder and not in a navbar folder.

thank you, however i now have gotten this error after all changesdjango.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: template/navbar.html
[15/Apr/2024 01:44:16] "GET /navbar/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71625

either change your folder name to be template or use templete as the path (because currently you have two different things (difference in a vs e before the t))

hi. i updated my photos. if you can see why its still not working for me. thank you, i have added my settings and views

follow this directory structure
myapp
-- templates
-- myapp
-- navbar
-- navbar.html
import os
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]


You defined
"DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],

for which django will look for templates folder in your app but you named it templete and that's why django view is unable to find your templates. and you should create a folder inside templates and another folder with name of your app and then put templates init.
Edit your templates folders like

myapp -> templates -> myapp -> navbar.html


This method will be done and seen
views.py
def navbar(request)
        return render(request, "navbar.html")

